# Error al enviar variables desde Ajax a PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estuve mirando por todo `Stackoverflow`, pero no encuentro forma de que funcione mi código.

Básicamente es un formulario de contacto y quiero enviar las variables a un `PHP` por medio de `ajax`.

**Javascript**

```
<script>

    $('#template-contactform-submit').click(function(){

        var email = $('#template-contactform-email').val();
        var nombre = $('#template-contactform-name').val();
        var telefono = $('#template-contactform-phone').val();
        var mensaje = $('#template-contactform-message').val();
        var asunto = $('#template-contactform-subject').val();
        var datos = 'email=' + email + '&nombre=' + nombre + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&mensaje=' + mensaje + '&asunto=' + asunto;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/contact-form.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: datos
        })

        .done(function(res){
            $('#respuesta3').html(res)
        })

        .fail(function(fail_resp){
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: 'No se ha podido realizar la suscripción. Intentelo nuevamente más tarde..',
                icon: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar'
                })
        })

    });

</script>
```

y acá el **PHP** que lo recibe

```
<?php

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

    if ($nombre=='' | $email=='' | $telefono=='' | $asunto=='' | $mensaje==''){

        echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');</script>";

    }else{

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
        require("class.phpmailer.php");
        include("class.smtp.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
        $cuerpo="Consulta desde <a href='http://tertiarium.com.ar/'>Tertiarium</a><br />
        <br />
        Nombre y apellido: ".$nombre."<br />
        ===============================<br />
        Email: ".$email."<br />
        Telefono: ".$telefono."<br />
        ===============================<br />
        Asunto: ".$asunto." <br />
        ===============================<br />
        Consulta: ".$mensaje."<br />";
        try {
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Port       = 587;  // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password
            $mail->AddReplyTo($email);
            $mail->AddAddress('mail@gmail.com', 'Tertiarium');
            $mail->AddCC('mail@gmail.com', 'Tertiarium');
            $mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Tertiarium');
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = "Suscripcion de Tertiarium";

            $mail->MsgHTML($cuerpo);
            $mail->Send();

            echo "<script>Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Suscripción realizada!',
                    text: 'Pronto nos pondremos en contacto.',
                    icon: 'success',
                    timeOut: 5000,
                    });</script>";


            if(!$Correo->Send()){
                echo "Error: $Correo->ErrorInfo";
            } else {
                echo "Mensaje enviado";
            }
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
        }
    }

?>
```

El error que recibo es: **error 500**

---

Ahora lo estoy pasando como **JSON** pero sigue fallando. Tira error 500

```
<script>

        $('#template-contactform-submit').click(function(){

            var email = $('#template-contactform-email').val();
            var nombre = $('#template-contactform-name').val();
            var telefono = $('#template-contactform-phone').val();
            var mensaje = $('#template-contactform-message').val();
            var asunto = $('#template-contactform-subject').val();
            var datos = {email: email,nombre:nombre,telefono:telefono,mensaje:mensaje,asunto:asunto};

            $.ajax({
                url: 'include/contact-form.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: datos
            })

            .done(function(res){
                $('#respuesta3').html(res)
            })

            .fail(function(fail_resp){
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Error!',
                    text: 'No se ha podido realizar la suscripción. Intentelo nuevamente más tarde..',
                    icon: 'error',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar'
                    })
            })

        });

    </script>
```

**NOTA: Tengo el mismo código funcionando en el campo de suscripción, en el que solo se pone el email para que lleguen newsletters. Solo falla cuando son varios campos como en este caso, el formulario de contacto**

Comment: ¿Ese es el PHP completo? Lo he probado y funciona  todo correctamente. Muestra lo que tienes en el PHP.

Comment: Actualizado....

Comment: El error 500 es un error al ejecutar PHP. Deberías mirar en el log de error de tu servidor apache y en él aparecerá el mensaje de error, la línea, etc. Mucho me temo que está relacionado con la línea que pone `if(!$Correo->Send()){`, ya que no puedes llamar al método `Send()` de `NULL` (si `$Correo` no ha sido definida, [vale `NULL`](https://www.php.net/es/language.types.null)).

Comment: En el servidor parece que te falta incluir ciertos archivos de PHPMailer ([revisa un poco los ejemplos de código](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)), aparte de otros errores que los compañeros te han indicado en sus respuestas. Por otra parte tienes un lío en el código PHP: salidas con la etiqueta `<script>`, salidas con `echo`, etc. Cuando a una petición Ajax le pones esto: `dataType: "json",` significa que el tipo de respuesta que esperas de retorno es un json. No puedes por tanto emitir salidas variopintas, sino únicamente un script. Debes controlar el código y emitir un json al final

Comment: Dinno, ¿sigue fallando tu código? ¿Has comprobado las nuevas respuestas que te han proporcionado? Si ninguna te soluciona el problema, o lo hace parcialmente, y si sigues interesado en solucionar este problema háznoslo saber. Podemos abrir un chat para acelerar el intercambio de información y experiencias.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes convertir tu

```
var datos = 'datos'
```

A un `.json` para luego en la peticion ajax, declarar el `dataType`y asi enviarlo.

```
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'include/contact-form.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data:({"uniId":"test"}),
         success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
           }
     });
```

Luego, tienes que procesar los datos en tu PHP.

Fuente en `Stackoverflow inglés`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041380/using-post-via-ajax-and-php-to-send-data

Tambien te puede servir:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948002/submitting-form-via-jquery-ajax-post-request/39949050

Comment: Ya lo probé y sigue tirando el mismo error. Edité la publicación y puse lo que tengo puesto actualmente.

Comment: Prueba con el segundo link que te puse. Revisa algun cierre `; } , )` faltante, ya que a veces puede ser ese el error. Prueba, enviando el done y fail dentro del $.ajax, como en la referencia... Estoy sin poder testear codigos etc... ya que estoy sin pc.

Comment: Ya probe y nada.. sigue igual

Answer (score 1):

Se genera un error HTTP 500 cuando se ha producido algún error al ejecutar o analizar el script PHP.

Deberías consultar en el log de error de tu servidor Apache. En él aparecerá el mensaje de error, el nombre de archivo y línea en el que se produjo.

Existen dos posibles causas del error:

En las siguientes líneas:

```
if(!$Correo->Send()){
  echo "Error: $Correo->ErrorInfo";
```

No puedes llamar al método `Send()` de `NULL` ni acceder a su propiedad `ErrorInfo`. Como `$Correo` no ha sido definida, [valdrá `NULL`](https://www.php.net/es/language.types.null)) y `NULL` no tiene ni métodos ni propiedades. Creo que por error confundiste ese nombre de variable con `$mail`.

También podría ser la línea:

```
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
```

Ya que `phpmailerException` no existe, sería [`PHPMailer\Exception`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/Exception.php#L28).

Tu código corregido quedaría:

```
try {
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->Port       = 587;  // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
  $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password
  $mail->AddReplyTo($email);
  $mail->AddAddress('mail@gmail.com', 'Tertiarium');
  $mail->AddCC('mail@gmail.com', 'Tertiarium');
  $mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Tertiarium');
  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = "Suscripcion de Tertiarium";
  $mail->MsgHTML($cuerpo);
  echo "<script>Swal.fire({
    title: 'Suscripción realizada!',
    text: 'Pronto nos pondremos en contacto.',
    icon: 'success',
    timeOut: 5000,
    });</script>";
  if ($mail->Send() === false) {
    echo "Error: ", htmlspecialchars($mail->ErrorInfo);
  } else {
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

PD: Te recomiendo no usar `PHPMailer\Exception::errorMessage()` ya que lo único que hace es [envolver en HTML el mensaje de error](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/cc8da73fa21f59ee57281bf591d223fe8971b98e/src/Exception.php#L35), quedando fuera de tu alcance si eso es lo que querías hacer o no. En su lugar, te recomiendo que te acostumbres a usar [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) cuando envíes texto al navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer no formateas de forma correcta tus datos, razón por la cual no se envían.

Quiza funcionaria bien si tu petición fuera de tipo `get`, aunque no estoy seguro.

Pero Intenta lo siguiente, cambia:

```
var datos = 'email=' + email + '&nombre=' + nombre + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&mensaje=' + mensaje + '&asunto=' + asunto;
```

por un objeto `json`, es la mejor forma de enviar datos por `ajax`:

```
var datos = {email: email,nombre:nombre,telefono:telefono,mensaje:mensaje,asunto:asunto};
```

Si el resto de tu codigo esta bien bastara con modificar dicha linea.

**Edicion**

Una vez que pusiste tu codigo php, se puede apreciar mejor el problema, aunque no se puede probar todas las funciones, en lo personal jamas he utilizado `|` como operador lógico, también lo busque para ver si dicho operador existe y no tuve éxito encontrándolo, así que te aconsejo cambiar:

```
if ($nombre=='' | $email=='' | $telefono=='' | $asunto=='' | $mensaje=='')
```

Por:

```
if ($nombre=='' || $email=='' || $telefono=='' || $asunto=='' || $mensaje=='')
```

Que básicamente seria cambiar `|` por `||`, que es el operador `OR` en `php`.

Comment: Sigue tirando el error 500... En el PHP le tengo que tocar algo?

Comment: @Dinno los errores 500 son errores de servidor (PHP), no tienen nada que ver con el código Javascript (cliente). Tienes que revisar tu código PHP, puede que haya en él algún error de sintaxis o algo así. Si editas la pregunta poniendo el código PHP completo podremos ayudarte mejor. En cuanto al envío de datos, tienes que construir el objeto como se indica al final de esta respuesta: `var datos = {email: email,nombre:nombre ...}`

Comment: Ahí lo subí completo al php

Comment: @Dinno, edite mi respuesta, quiza esta vez encuentres la solucion.

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es simple, al momento de pasar las variables lo que mandas es una cadena no variables en si, es decir solo mandas una variable que es datos y esa variable lleva la cadena que armaste.
`'email=' + email + '&nombre=' + nombre + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&mensaje=' + mensaje + '&asunto=' + asunto`

Entonces como podemos pasar las variables de una forma sencilla sin tantos rollos y sin codificar en **json**, simple.

Declaramos una variable FormData:

```
var datos = new FormData();
```

Luego agregamos cada una de las variables que intentas mandar:

```
datos.append("email", email);
datos.append("nombre", nombre);
datos.append("telefono", telefono);
datos.append("mensaje", mensaje);
datos.append("asunto", asunto);
```

Luego en tu estructura **ajax** lo dejas igual.

Ahora en **PHP** podemos recibir las variables correctamente, cual es la diferencia a como lo tenias, simple, antes solo mandabas una variable en si que es la **"datos"** donde tenia una cadena, ahora mandas todas las variables que intentas enviar en tu correo.